# How to loop through a carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

what is the best way to loop through a carousel? Is there a possibility to know when the slides have reached the end and take them back to the start and vice versa?. I've tried to use  the "--items-per-screen" variable from CSS but it worked only in the desktop version, I couldn't fix it on the mobile version

```js
function MoveElements () {
   let initialCounter= 0;
   
function nextElement () {

 $(":root")[0].style.setProperty("--slider-index",++initialCounter);

}

function prevElement () {

 $(":root")[0].style.setProperty("--slider-index", --initialCounter);

}
  $('.carouselnav.next').click(nextElement)
$('.carouselnav.prev').click(prevElement)
} 
MoveElements ();
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
:root{
 --handle-size:3rem;
 --img-gap:.25rem;
 --slider-index:0;
 --items-per-screen:5;
}
body{
  background:#f3f3f3;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
 
  position:relative;
}
.carouselcontainer{
   max-width:1360px;
  margin:50px auto;
  background:#f1f1f1;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.caroufredsel_wrapper{
  width:100%;
}
.shopWindow{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
   transform: translateX(calc(var(--slider-index) * -100%));
  transition:transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.96, -0.17, 0.07, 0.80);
  
}
.shopWindow .grid-unit {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 144px;
    /*width: calc(100% / 5);*/
    width:calc(100% / var( --items-per-screen));
  max-width:100%;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.shopWindow .thumb{
  position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 45px 10px;
    background: #fff;
}
.shopWindow .grid-unit .grid-unit-inner .item .thumb .img-responsive {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
.shopWindow .item .itemInfo {
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: #fafafa;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}
.shopWindow .item .trademark {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.shopWindow .item .title {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.shopWindow .item .trademark a {
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.shopWindow .item .title a {
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.shopWindow .item .campaignContainer {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 30px;
}
.shopWindow .item .campaignContainer .priceContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Inter',sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
}
.shopWindow .item .campaignContainer .priceContainer .price, .shopWindow .item .campaignContainer .priceContainer .discount {
    color: #303030;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 27px;
}
.carouselcontainer .carouselnav {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ececec;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
}
div.carouselcontainer.horizontal a.carouselnav.prev {
    left: 0;
   
}
div.carouselcontainer.horizontal a.carouselnav.next {
    right: 4px;
   
}
.carouselcontainer.horizontal .carouselnav.next:before {
    content: '>';
}
.carouselcontainer.horizontal .carouselnav.prev:before {
    content: '<';
}

.carouselcontainer a.carouselnav {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
.carouselcontainer .carouselnav:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 40px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.carouselcontainer .carouselnav:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0 !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1269px) and (min-width: 769px) {
  .grid-unit{
    
  --items-per-screen:3;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid-unit{
    
  --items-per-screen:2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="carouselcontainer horizontal">
 <div class="caroufredsel_wrapper">
   <div class="shopWindow">
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </img>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </img>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </img>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </img>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
     <div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-unit">
  <div class="grid-unit-inner">
    
    <div class="item">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="badges"></div>
        <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
        <a href="" >
          <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="itemInfo">
        <div class="trademark">
          <a href="">KTM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
        </div>
        <div class="campaignContainer">
          <div class="priceContainer">
            <span class="price">6490</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
     </div>
  <a class="carouselnav next" href="#">
     
   </a>
   <a class="carouselnav prev" href="#">
     
   </a>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: U need to make an array of it instead doing hardcoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the total number of screens according to the current settings:

```
let screensTotal = Math.ceil(itemsTotal / itemsPerScreen);
```

I strongly recommend renaming the `initialCounter` variable to `currentScreen`  (it's just more self-explanatory).
Each time you call `nextElement()` the currentScreen variable is increased.
If it becomes larger than the number of total screens, you need to reset it to 0.

#### Example

```js
//count total items
let carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-unit");
let itemsTotal = carouselItems.length;

//count total screens
let styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
let itemsPerScreen = parseFloat(styles.getPropertyValue("--items-per-screen"));
let screensTotal = Math.ceil(itemsTotal / itemsPerScreen);

// update items to screen ratios on window resize
window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
  styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
  itemsPerScreen = parseFloat(styles.getPropertyValue("--items-per-screen"));
  screensTotal = Math.ceil(itemsTotal / itemsPerScreen);
});

function MoveElements() {
  let currentScreen = 0;

  function nextElement() {
    currentScreen++;
    if (currentScreen >= screensTotal) {
      currentScreen = 0;
    }
    //update css var
    $(":root")[0].style.setProperty("--slider-index", currentScreen);
  }

  function prevElement() {
    currentScreen--;
    //got to last screen
    if (currentScreen < 0) {
      currentScreen = screensTotal - 1;
    }
    $(":root")[0].style.setProperty("--slider-index", currentScreen);
  }
  $(".carouselnav.next").click(nextElement);
  $(".carouselnav.prev").click(prevElement);
}
MoveElements();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --handle-size: 3rem;
  --img-gap: 0.25rem;
  --slider-index: 0;
  --items-per-screen: 5;
}

body {
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.carouselcontainer {
  max-width: 1360px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caroufredsel_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.shopWindow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--slider-index) * -100%));
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.96, -0.17, 0.07, 0.8);
}

.shopWindow .grid-unit {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 144px;
  /*width: calc(100% / 5);*/
  width: calc(100% / var(--items-per-screen));
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.shopWindow .thumb {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 45px 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.shopWindow .grid-unit .grid-unit-inner .item .thumb .img-responsive {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.shopWindow .item .itemInfo {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.shopWindow .item .trademark {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.shopWindow .item .title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.shopWindow .item .trademark a {
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.shopWindow .item .title a {
  line-height: 19px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.shopWindow .item .campaignContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.shopWindow .item .campaignContainer .priceContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
}

.shopWindow .item .campaignContainer .priceContainer .price,
.shopWindow .item .campaignContainer .priceContainer .discount {
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.carouselcontainer .carouselnav {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ececec;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
}

div.carouselcontainer.horizontal a.carouselnav.prev {
  left: 0;
}

div.carouselcontainer.horizontal a.carouselnav.next {
  right: 4px;
}

.carouselcontainer.horizontal .carouselnav.next:before {
  content: ">";
}

.carouselcontainer.horizontal .carouselnav.prev:before {
  content: "<";
}

.carouselcontainer a.carouselnav {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.carouselcontainer .carouselnav:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.carouselcontainer .carouselnav:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0 !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1269px) and (min-width: 769px) {
   :root {
    --items-per-screen: 3;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   :root {
    --items-per-screen: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="carouselcontainer horizontal">
    <div class="caroufredsel_wrapper">
      <div class="shopWindow">
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <a href="">
              </a>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <a href="">
                </a>
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">
                  </a><a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">

                </a>
              </div>
              <a href="">
              </a>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <a href="">
                </a>
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">
                  </a><a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">

                </a>
              </div>
              <a href="">
              </a>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <a href="">
                </a>
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">
                  </a><a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214369/bergamont-grandurance-rd-5-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-unit">
          <div class="grid-unit-inner">

            <div class="item">
              <div class="thumb">
                <div class="badges"></div>
                <a href="" class="addfavourite"></a>
                <a href="">
                  <img class="img-responsive lazy" src="https://03.cdn37.se/p6/images/2.2214257/trek-marlin-6-2022.jpeg" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="itemInfo">
                <div class="trademark">
                  <a href="">KTM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                  <a href="">Wild Cross 24</a>
                </div>
                <div class="campaignContainer">
                  <div class="priceContainer">
                    <span class="price">6490</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-container"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carouselnav next" href="#">

    </a>
    <a class="carouselnav prev" href="#">

    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx, but it still doesn't work @herrstrietzel

Comment: @Mohamad E. sorry forgot to include jquery for the snippet. Have a look once again.

Comment: Thank you so much, i've been testing for more than three weeks , i'll go through it and learn how did you fix it